# How To Detect The First Collided Object Using Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk, collision-detection

function scene:create( event )
-- include Corona's "physics" library
    local physics = require "physics"
    physics.start()
    -- Seed The Randomness of numbers
    math.randomseed(os.time())

```
-- Called when the scene's view does not exist.
-- 
-- INSERT code here to initialize the scene
-- e.g. add display objects to 'sceneGroup', add touch listeners, etc.
local sound = audio.loadStream("pudi.mp3")
audio.play(sound, { channel=1, loops=-1, fadein=3000})

local sceneGroup = self.view
-- create a grey rectangle as the backdrop
local background = display.newImageRect("background.jpg", screenW, screenH )
background.anchorX = 0
background.anchorY = 0

local finishline = display.newRect( 0, 450, 750, 5 )
physics.addBody(finishline,"static",{friction=2.0,bounce=0.3})
finishline.myName = "finishline"

local blueTurtle = display.newImageRect("blueturtle.png",33,42)
physics.addBody(blueTurtle,"dynamic",{friction=2.0,bounce=0})
blueTurtle.myName = "Blue Turtle"

local redTurtle = display.newImageRect("redturtle.png",33,42)
physics.addBody(redTurtle,"dynamic",{friction=2.0,bounce=0})
redTurtle.myName = "Red Turtle"

local greenTurtle = display.newImageRect("turtlegreen.png",33,42)
physics.addBody(greenTurtle,"dynamic",{friction=2.0,bounce=0})
greenTurtle.myName = "Green Turtle"


blueTurtle.x = 50
blueTurtle.y = 25

redTurtle.x = 150
redTurtle.y = 25

greenTurtle.x = 250
greenTurtle.y = 25

local function numberGenerator1()
    local myRandomNumber = math.random(80000, 180000)   
    timer.performWithDelay( 1000, numberGenerator)
   return myRandomNumber
end

local function numberGenerator2()
    local myRandomNumber = math.random(80000, 180000)   
    timer.performWithDelay( 1000, numberGenerator)
   return myRandomNumber
end

local function numberGenerator3()
    local myRandomNumber = math.random(80000, 180000)   
    timer.performWithDelay( 1000, numberGenerator)
   return myRandomNumber
end

time1 = numberGenerator1()
time2 = numberGenerator2()
time3 = numberGenerator3()


transition.to(blueTurtle,{x=50,y=350,time=time1})
transition.to(redTurtle,{x=150,y=350,time=time2})
transition.to(greenTurtle,{x=250,y=350,time=time3})

local function onCollision(event)
    if (event.phase == "began") then
        if(event.object2.myName == 'Blue Turtle') then
             print("Blue Turtle Wins")
             event.object2 = nil
             composer.gotoScene( "instruction", "fade", 500 )    

        elseif(event.object2.myName == 'Red Turtle') then
             print("Red Turtle Wins")
             event.object2 = nil
             composer.gotoScene( "instruction", "fade", 500 )    

        elseif(event.object2.myName == 'Green Turtle') then               
             print("Green Turtle Wins")      
             event.object2 = nil
             composer.gotoScene( "instruction", "fade", 500 )    


        end 
    end 


end

Runtime:addEventListener("collision",onCollision)
```

end

I like to get the first turtle who hit the finish line then show a GUI on which turtle wins.

Comment: By the way guys the goto scene inside the if else statement does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the gotoScene() does work inside the if statement ..
to fix your problem here what you need to do:

1- Insert all your display objects to the sceneGroup, so when you go to other scenes all objects are removed from the screen.

```
sceneGroup:insert(background)
sceneGroup:insert(finishline)
sceneGroup:insert(redTurtle)
sceneGroup:insert(blueTurtle)
sceneGroup:insert(greenTurtle)
```

2- Before leaving the scene you need to stop the audio, remove the eventListeners, cancel the timers, and the transitions you are using .. I notices you have some errors in the timer fucntions, I so I would modify your code as:

-Instead of using numberGenerator, you need to call the same fucntion for the purpose you need the timer for.

```
 local function numberGenerator1()
        local myRandomNumber = math.random(80000, 180000)
        timer1 = timer.performWithDelay( 1000, numberGenerator1)
       return myRandomNumber
    end

 local function numberGenerator2()
        local myRandomNumber = math.random(80000, 180000)
        timer2 = timer.performWithDelay( 1000, numberGenerator2)
       return myRandomNumber
    end

 local function numberGenerator3()
        local myRandomNumber = math.random(80000, 180000)
        timer3 = timer.performWithDelay( 1000, numberGenerator3)
       return myRandomNumber
    end

time1 = numberGenerator1()
time2 = numberGenerator2()
time3 = numberGenerator3()


blueTrans = transition.to(blueTurtle,{x=50,y=350,time=time1})
redTrans = transition.to(redTurtle,{x=150,y=350,time=time2})
greenTrans = transition.to(greenTurtle,{x=250,y=350,time=time3})
```

and then you clean up your scene .. so inside the scene:hide()

```
Runtime:removeEventListener("collision",onCollision)
transition.cancel ( blueTrans )
transition.cancel ( redTrans )
transition.cancel ( greenTrans )
timer.cancel(timer1)
timer.cancel(timer2)
timer.cancel(timer3)
```

3 - for the gotoScene() you can pass a param to determine which turtle won, so I modified it inside the If statements:

```
composer.gotoScene( "instruction", {effect = "fade",time = 500, params = { winningTurtle = "Blue" }}) 

composer.gotoScene( "instruction", {effect = "fade",time = 500, params = { winningTurtle = "Red" }})

composer.gotoScene( "instruction", {effect = "fade",time = 500, params = { winningTurtle = "Green" }} )
```

4- Finally.. in the instruction.lua .. inside the scene:show()

```
local prevScene = composer.getSceneName( "previous" )
composer.removeScene(prevScene)
```

and for accessing the params sent by the previous file

```
local params = event.params
print("The Winning Turtle is :" .. params.winningTurtle)
```

Comment: this game is a racing game the random timer is for the movement of the turtles my point is how can I promp the screen to show who first hit the finishline by the way thanks for the reply